# What are the advantages of merging multiple .NET assemblies into one?

Tags: .net-assembly, ilmerge

I've seen discussions of techniques to merging multiple assemblies into one (e.g. ilmerge). I am scratching my head on why does one want to do so. Is there any reason **other than** the obvious "one file is easier to deploy/track/maintain/reference"?

Comment: There's a few good reasons why in this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376/ilmerge-best-practices

Comment: ILMerge is a programmer's tool.  Creating an installer so everything is merged into setup.exe is usually regarded as a mysterious black art invoked by somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons may be:

- Small utility programs, for example when you want to just copy/paste the whole program to a server without any folders or anything.
- Deployment scenarios where you want to keep minimal amount of files that should be copied, uploaded to FTP etc, for example installers.
- NuGet packages where you want to keep the amount of added references to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster startup time associated with decreased I/O on an application's Cold Startup. Best way to see how much improvement time can be saved is to measure as each app is different: number of assemblies, size of assemblies, etc.