# Using ILMerge for combining assemblies

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, assemblies, ilmerge

I have written a Visual Basic.net application and am currently using a .DLL that I have created myself.

I have read online that it is possible to use ILMerge to combine two assemblies together. Can I please have some advice on whether I should use this technique and if so, how it is done.

Comment: This is an open ended question that is probably better asked over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (ie, there is no definitive answer, and will potentially start a debate. For example, look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376/ilmerge-best-practices/13205241#13205241)

Comment: Most Windows users will expect you to use another merge tool.  One that produces a single file called Setup.exe.  Surely you know it.