# Deploy WinForm application generating single exe file

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I need to deploy a WinForm application and I need to generate just 1 .exe file.

I tried with ClickOnce but it generates also a manifest file, so I can't use it,
and I can not use the Release folder content because there aerseveral files (eg. strings resources)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There's a little tool called `ILMerge`.
With this it is possible to merge several dlls and exe into one exe.

I don't know if it is possible to integrate resource files as well, but i don't think so.

Have a look at:
[ILMerge Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376/ilmerge-best-practices)