# how to use ILMerge to combine several assemblies into one

Tags: .net, ilmerge

I've been looking for the way to combine multiple dlls into an exe, then I find that ILMerge is a good tool to do it. but after downloading ilmerge 3.0.40 nuget package, I don't know what to do next.

I have found a reference : ILMerge Best Practices([ILMerge Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376/ilmerge-best-practices)), but it didn't show specific steps for me.

what do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution:

After installing the package and building the application, I copy all files in net452(solution packages folder -> ILMerge folder -> tools -> net452).Then I paste it to the path my app built(\bin\Debug).

Then I open the command prompt and cd to my directory and insert the following code:

```
ILMerge.exe /target:winexe /target:exe /out:filepath nameofexe mydll
```

It works well!